# XSLT : copy from another file and apply templates

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two xml files, the first one (the matched file) contains id field that need to be extracted.
I need to export this id to the second xml.

first.xml :

```
<A>
...
<data>blabla&lt;id&gt;15201&lt;id&gt;blabla</data>
...
</A>
```

seconnd.xml :

```
<B>
...
<id>4621</id>
...
</B>
```

Expected result :

```
<B>
...
<id>15201</id>
...
</B>
```

I know that it would be easier to match the second file and include id from first, but it's impossible in my case, i have to match first.xml

This is what i tried to do :

```
...
<xsl:variable name="id" select="substring-before(substring-after(//*[local-name()='data'], 'id&gt;'), '&lt;')" />

<xsl:variable name="file" select="document('second.xml')" />
...
<xsl:template match="id"><id><xsl:value-of select="$id" /></id></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$file" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
...
```

But i still get this as result (the file is copied but the templates are not applied):

```
<B>
...
<id>4621</id>
...
</B>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$file/node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It worked, thanks !
Can you tell me what the difference between <xsl:apply-templates /> and <xsl:apply-templates select="$file/node()"/> ?

Comment: With the `<xsl:copy-of select="$file" />` you are copying the document `$file` to the output, completely unchanged and unprocessed. And your `<xsl:apply-templates />` simply processes the original input document, which you don't want to process, other than extracting the value for the id.